# Java Integer memory allocation

Tags: java, memory, integer

Hey I am trying to understand the following code snippet.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer i1 = 1000;
    Integer i2 = 1000;
    if(i1 != i2) System.out.println("different objects");
    if(i1.equals(i2)) System.out.println("meaningfully equal");
    Integer i3 = 10;
    Integer i4 = 10;
    if(i3 == i4) System.out.println("same object");
    if(i3.equals(i4)) System.out.println("meaningfully equal");
}
```

This method runs all of the println instructions. That is i1 != i2 is true, but i3 == i4. At first glance this strikes me as strange, they should be all different as references. I can figure out that if I pass the same **byte** value (-128 to 127) to i3 and i4 they will be always equal as references, but any other value will yield them as different.

I can't explain this, can you point me to some documentation or give some helpful insights?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Autoboxing `int` values to `Integer` objects will use a cache for common values (as you've identified them). This is specified in the [JLS at §5.1.7 Boxing Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.7):

> If the value `p` being boxed is `true`, `false`, a `byte`, a `char` in the range `\u0000` to `\u007f`, or an `int` or `short` number between `-128` and `127`, then let `r1` and `r2` be the results of any two boxing conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `r1 == r2.`

Note that this will **only** be applied when the language auto-boxes a value for you *or* when you use [`Integer.valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29). Using [`new Integer(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer%28int%29) will **always** produce a new `Integer` object.

Minor hint: a JVM implementation is free to cache values outside of those ranges as well, because the opposite is not specified. I've not yet seen such an implementation, however.

Answer (score 2):

Java keeps a pool of Integer between -128 and 128. If you use Integer outside of this range, new Integer objects are created. That's the explanation.

Here you can see it in the Java source code:

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
        if(i >= -128 && i <= IntegerCache.high)
            return IntegerCache.cache[i + 128];
        else
            return new Integer(i);
    }
```

Comment: I take it an int literal used in an Integer context is converted using `Integer.valueOf(...)` and not `new Integer(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

Integers from -128 to 127 are wrapped into fixed objects. That's why you get i3 == i4.